# Variable argument number in pgfmath

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I am trying to understand how to define a PGF function with a variable number of arguments.  Here is a minimal working example of what I am trying to do:

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pgfmath}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{theFnIDef}{...}{%
\begingroup
   \pgfmatharray{#1}{0}%
   % \pgfmatharray{#1}{1}%   <---  This line always fails
   \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
\endgroup
}

\begin{document}

theFnIDef(2,3): \pgfmathparse{theFnIDef(2,3)}\pgfmathresult

theFnIDef(2,3,5,8): \pgfmathparse{theFnIDef(2,3,5,8)}\pgfmathresult

\end{document}
```

This always outputs:

theFnIDef(2,3): 3

theFnIDef(2,3,5,8): 8

which is basically the last element.  I have tried other syntax (`\pgfmathparse{array(#1,1)}`) and calling the function with additional curly braces (`\pgfmathparse{theFnIDef({2,3})}`), but nothing works.

In the documentation for version 3.1.9a, on page 1050, it says,

> ...although it is a fairly simple task...

as can be seen in this screen shot I took of the documentation:

[image: screenshot of pgf documentation 3.1.9a, page 1050]

but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.  If anybody could help, that would be great.

Comment: The function `\pgfmatharray` expects as its first argument a comma separated list of values. The `...` argument specification doesn't return the arguments in commas but in braced groups.

Comment: @Skillmon I figured that out using your explations in another answer and finding out about \tl_log:n.  I still can't figure out how to use {2}{3}{5}{8} in the rest of the function definition.  Any pointers to where I could find more specific info on that?  :-(

Comment: I think I have finally found a way:
```latex
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \myseq
\clist_new:N \myclist
\cs_set_eq:NN \@seqsetsplit \seq_set_split:Nnn
\cs_set_eq:NN \@clistfromseq \clist_set_from_seq:NN
\cs_set_eq:NN \@seqcount \seq_count:N
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{theFnIDef}{...}{%
   \begingroup
   \@seqsetsplit \myseq {} {#1}
   \@clistfromseq \myclist \myseq
   \edef\bla{\@seqcount \myseq}
   % \edef\bla{4}
   \pgfmatharray{\myclist}{1}%
   \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
   \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```
seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the internal defintion of the `array` function which *does* expect its first argument to be a list of braced elements, i.e.

```
{2}{3}
```

and

```
{2}{3}{5}{8}
```

in your case, which is exactly what the internal defintion of your `theFnIDef` functions has to deal with (because that's what you always do with `\pgfmathdeclarefunction{<name>}`, you actually define `\pgfmath<name>@`).

So

```
\pgfmatharray@{#1}{<num>}%
```

will give you the `<num>`th element of your parameters by storing it in `\pgfmathresult`.

The `array@` function itself just loops through all given `{…}` until it has reached the one you've asked for.

---

In the code below, I'm getting the size of the `#1` array by using the `dim@` function (same rules apply → using the internal one) which also just loops through all elements incrementing a counter everytime it en*counter*s an element.

This is a very inefficient (O(n²)?) way to access all parameters since it involves multiple loops that do nothing with the actual elements.

But for a more efficient (or easier?) way to use all your elements the actual definition of the function is needed.

---

This code does … nothing but returns the number of parameters (basically just the first call to `dim@`) and writes the elements to the log.

It would be better to also do something with the parameters while we're iterating through them anyway. In [another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655751/16595) the last eight of ten parameters get simply forwarded to other functions (that do expect eight arguments). This is done via the `\pgfmath@util@…` functions (and a bit expansion control).

---

There's also a `\pgfmathloop` … `\repeatpgfmathloop` with its own self-incrementing counter `\pgfmathcounter` (not a TeX count!) but that starts at 1, not at 0, so we would need

```
\pgfmatharray@{#1}{\numexpr\pgfmathcounter-1\relax}%
```

in the loop (and `\the\numexpr\pgfmathcounter-1\relax` in the `\typeout`) to get the PGFmath numbering of the array's index.

I've opted instead for the `\pgfutil@loop` (which should be equal to the LaTeX `\@loop` but is defined across all platforms that can run PGFmath.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{theFnIDef}{...}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfmathdim@{#1}%
    \let\pgfmatharraysize\pgfmathresult
    \typeout{Array #1 has \pgfmatharraysize\space elements.}%
    \c@pgf@countb=0
    \pgfutil@loop
      \pgfmatharray@{#1}{\c@pgf@countb}%
      \typeout{Argument No \the\c@pgf@countb\space is \pgfmathresult.}%
      \advance\c@pgf@countb by 1
      \ifnum\c@pgf@countb<\pgfmatharraysize\relax
    \pgfutil@repeat
    \let\pgfmathresult\pgfmatharraysize
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult % will just return the number of elements
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
theFnIDef(2,3): \pgfmathprint{theFnIDef(2,3)}

theFnIDef(2,3,5,8): \pgfmathprint{theFnIDef(2,3,5,8)}
\end{document}
```

### Output (Log)

```
Array {2}{3} has 2 elements.
Argument No 0 is 2.
Argument No 1 is 3.
Array {2}{3}{5}{8} has 4 elements.
Argument No 0 is 2.
Argument No 1 is 3.
Argument No 2 is 5.
Argument No 3 is 8.
```