# Function within a function in \pgfmathdeclarefunction

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath, pgfmathparse

I'm trying to plot a complex function and to that end I'm using `pgfmathdeclarefunction`. Still, I'm unable to get it to work, I get the error:

> ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfmathNi@.

I start wondering whether what I'm trying to do is even possible: to call a function within another function in the definition of `pgfmathdeclarefunction`. This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{detG}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1*(#7*(#4 - #6)*(#2 - #8) - #5*(#2 - #6)*(#4 - #8) + #3*(#2 - #4)*(#6 - #8)) + #3*#5*(#4 - #6)*(#2 - #8) - #3*#7*(#2 - #6)*(#4 - #8) + #5*#7*(#2 - #4)*(#6 - #8)
  }%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hii}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#5*#7*#4*(#6 - #8) + #3*#5*(#4 - #6)*#8 + #3*#7*#6*(-#4 + #8)
  }%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hji}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#3*#4*(#6 - #8) + #7*(#4 - #6)*#8 + #5*#6*(-#4 + #8)
  }%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hki}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#3*#5*(-#4 + #6) + #3*#7*(#4 - #8) + #5*#7*(-#6 + #8)
  }%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hli}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#7*(-#4 + #6) + #5*(#4 - #8) + #3*(-#6 + #8)
  }%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Ni}{10}{%
  \pgfmathparse{Hii(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8) + Hji(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8)*#9 + Hki(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8)*#10 + Hli(#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6,#7,#8)*#9*#10
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[]

\addplot3[surf,domain=0:1, samples=20] { Ni(-1,-1,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,x,y) / detG(-1,-1,0,-1,0,0,-1,0)};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT**
Thanks to the answer provided by @Qrrbrbirlbel I could plot one function. I managed to generalize the code to plot 4 of these functions (very similar). The functions should make a tent, so that each function plotted in its own square domain has a value of 1 at coordinate (0,0). This is the result I have so far, and although it works, there is a lot of repeated code:

[image: 4 functions Ni, Nj, Nk, and Nl]

and the current code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{detGi}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{-(#1*(#7*(#4-#6)*(#2-#8)-#5*(#2-#6)*(#4-#8)+#3*(#2-#4)*(#6-#8))
    +#3*#5*(#4-#6)*(#2-#8)-#3*#7*(#2-#6)*(#4-#8)+#5*#7*(#2-#4)*(#6-#8))}}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{detGj}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{-(#1*(#7*(#4-#6)*(#2-#8)-#5*(#2-#6)*(#4-#8)+#3*(#2-#4)*(#6-#8))
    +#3*#5*(#4-#6)*(#2-#8)-#3*#7*(#2-#6)*(#4-#8)+#5*#7*(#2-#4)*(#6-#8))}}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{detGk}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{-(#1*(#7*(#4-#6)*(#2-#8)-#5*(#2-#6)*(#4-#8)+#3*(#2-#4)*(#6-#8))
    +#3*#5*(#4-#6)*(#2-#8)-#3*#7*(#2-#6)*(#4-#8)+#5*#7*(#2-#4)*(#6-#8))}}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{detGl}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{-(#1*(#7*(#4-#6)*(#2-#8)-#5*(#2-#6)*(#4-#8)+#3*(#2-#4)*(#6-#8))
    +#3*#5*(#4-#6)*(#2-#8)-#3*#7*(#2-#6)*(#4-#8)+#5*#7*(#2-#4)*(#6-#8))}}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hii}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#5*#7*#4*(#6-#8)+#3*#5*(#4-#6)*#8+#3*#7*#6*(-#4+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hji}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#3*#4*(#6-#8)+#7*(#4-#6)*#8+#5*#6*(-#4+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hki}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#3*#5*(-#4+#6)+#3*#7*(#4-#8)+#5*#7*(-#6+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hli}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#7*(-#4+#6)+#5*(#4-#8)+#3*(-#6+#8)}}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hij}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1*#7*#6*(#2-#8)+#1*#5*(-#2+#6)*#8+#5*#7*#2*(-#6+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hjj}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#5*#6*(#2-#8)+#7*(-#2+#6)*#8+#1*#2*(-#6+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hkj}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1*#5*(#2-#6)+#5*#7*(#6-#8)+#1*#7*(-#2+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hlj}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#7*(#2-#6)+#1*(#6-#8)+#5*(-#2+#8)}}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hik}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#3*#7*#2*(#4-#8)+#1*#3*(#2-#4)*#8+#1*#7*#4*(-#2+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hjk}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1*#2*(#4-#8)+#7*(#2-#4)*#8+#3*#4*(-#2+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hkk}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1*#3*(-#2+#4)+#1*#7*(#2-#8)+#3*#7*(-#4+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hlk}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#7*(-#2+#4)+#3*(#2-#8)+#1*(-#4+#8)}}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hil}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1*#5*#4*(#2-#6)+#1*#3*(-#2+#4)*#6+#3*#5*#2*(-#4+#6)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hjl}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#3*#4*(#2-#6)+#5*(-#2+#4)*#6+#1*#2*(-#4+#6)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hkl}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1*#3*(#2-#4)+#3*#5*(#4-#6)+#1*#5*(-#2+#6)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hll}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#5*(#2-#4)+#1*(#4-#6)+#3*(-#2+#6)}}



\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Ni}{2}{%
  \begingroup
    \def\vo##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/helper/##1}}% shortcut for here
    \pgfmathparse{\vo{Hii}+\vo{Hji}*#1+\vo{Hki}*#2+\vo{Hli}*#1*#2}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
  \endgroup
}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{NiDet}{2}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfmathNi@{#1}{#2}%
    \pgfmathdivide@{\pgfmathresult}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/helper/detGi}}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
  \endgroup
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Nj}{2}{%
  \begingroup
    \def\vo##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/helper/##1}}% shortcut for here
    \pgfmathparse{\vo{Hij}+\vo{Hjj}*#1+\vo{Hkj}*#2+\vo{Hlj}*#1*#2}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
  \endgroup
}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{NjDet}{2}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfmathNj@{#1}{#2}%
    \pgfmathdivide@{\pgfmathresult}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/helper/detGj}}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
  \endgroup
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Nk}{2}{%
  \begingroup
    \def\vo##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/helper/##1}}% shortcut for here
    \pgfmathparse{\vo{Hik}+\vo{Hjk}*#1+\vo{Hkk}*#2+\vo{Hlk}*#1*#2}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
  \endgroup
}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{NkDet}{2}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfmathNk@{#1}{#2}%
    \pgfmathdivide@{\pgfmathresult}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/helper/detGk}}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
  \endgroup
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Nl}{2}{%
  \begingroup
    \def\vo##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/helper/##1}}% shortcut for here
    \pgfmathparse{\vo{Hil}+\vo{Hjl}*#1+\vo{Hkl}*#2+\vo{Hll}*#1*#2}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
  \endgroup
}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{NlDet}{2}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfmathNl@{#1}{#2}%
    \pgfmathdivide@{\pgfmathresult}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/helper/detGl}}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
  \endgroup
}

\pgfkeys{
  /handlers/.pgfmath/.code=%
    \pgfmathparse{#1}\expandafter\pgfkeys@exp@call\expandafter{\pgfmathresult},
  /handlers/.pgfmath fpu/.code=%
    \begingroup\pgfset{fpu}\pgfmathparse{#1}\expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\pgfkeys@exp@call\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

% plot Nj in [-1,0]x[0,1]
\pgfplotsset{
  helper/Hij/.initial=0,  helper/Hjj/.initial=0,
  helper/Hkj/.initial=0,  helper/Hlj/.initial=0,
  helper/detGj/.initial=0,
  prepare matrix/.style={
    helper/Hij/.pgfmath fpu={Hij(#1)}, helper/Hjj/.pgfmath fpu={Hjj(#1)},
    helper/Hkj/.pgfmath fpu={Hkj(#1)}, helper/Hlj/.pgfmath fpu={Hlj(#1)},
    helper/detGj/.pgfmath fpu={detGj(#1)}
    }}
  
\addplot3[surf, domain=-1:0, y domain=0:1, samples=20, prepare matrix={-1,0,0,0,0,1,-1,1}]
  {NjDet(x,y)};
  
% plot Ni in [0,1]x[0,1]
\pgfplotsset{
  helper/Hii/.initial=0,  helper/Hji/.initial=0,
  helper/Hki/.initial=0,  helper/Hli/.initial=0,
  helper/detGi/.initial=0,
  prepare matrix/.style={
    helper/Hii/.pgfmath fpu={Hii(#1)}, helper/Hji/.pgfmath fpu={Hji(#1)},
    helper/Hki/.pgfmath fpu={Hki(#1)}, helper/Hli/.pgfmath fpu={Hli(#1)},
    helper/detGi/.pgfmath fpu={detGi(#1)}
    }}
  
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:1, y domain=0:1, samples=20, prepare matrix={0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1}]
  {NiDet(x,y)};
  
  
% plot Nk in [-1,0]x[-1,0]
\pgfplotsset{
  helper/Hik/.initial=0,  helper/Hjk/.initial=0,
  helper/Hkk/.initial=0,  helper/Hlk/.initial=0,
  helper/detGk/.initial=0,
  prepare matrix/.style={
    helper/Hik/.pgfmath fpu={Hik(#1)}, helper/Hjk/.pgfmath fpu={Hjk(#1)},
    helper/Hkk/.pgfmath fpu={Hkk(#1)}, helper/Hlk/.pgfmath fpu={Hlk(#1)},
    helper/detGk/.pgfmath fpu={detGk(#1)}
    }}

\addplot3[surf, domain=-1:0, y domain=-1:0, samples=20, prepare matrix={-1,-1,0,-1,0,0,-1,0}]
  {NkDet(x,y)};
  
% plot Nl in [0,1]x[-1,0]
\pgfplotsset{
  helper/Hil/.initial=0,  helper/Hjl/.initial=0,
  helper/Hkl/.initial=0,  helper/Hll/.initial=0,
  helper/detGl/.initial=0,
  prepare matrix/.style={
    helper/Hil/.pgfmath fpu={Hil(#1)}, helper/Hjl/.pgfmath fpu={Hjl(#1)},
    helper/Hkl/.pgfmath fpu={Hkl(#1)}, helper/Hll/.pgfmath fpu={Hll(#1)},
    helper/detGl/.pgfmath fpu={detGl(#1)}
    }}
  
\addplot3[surf, domain=0:1, y domain=-1:0, samples=20, prepare matrix={0,-1,1,-1,1,0,0,0}]
  {NlDet(x,y)};

  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since the `det` functions are the same, you don't need four of them. You can do `helper/detGk/.pgfmath fpu={detG(#1)}` and similar for the others, too. I'm surprised that the other functions are very similar but don't just reorder their arguments. I was hoping `Hji(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) = Hii(3,4,5,6,1,2,7,8)` but I guess not …

Comment: Yes that helped reduce the number of functions to only one detG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#10` won't work (that's a TeX limitation), the [PGFmanual states](https://tikz.dev/math-algorithms#%5Cpgfmathdeclarefunction)

> For functions with more than nine arguments, or functions with a variable number of arguments, these macros are only defined as taking *one* argument. The public macro expects its arguments to be comma separated, for example, `\pgfmathVariableArgs{1.1,3.5,-1.5,2.6}`. Each argument is parsed and passed on to the private macro as follows: `\pgfmathVariableArgs@{{1.1}{3.5}{-1.5}{2.6}}`. This means that some “extra work” will be required to access each argument (although it is a fairly simple task).

It really isn't too hard to convert. For convenience I changed the order of the arguments, they're now `Ni(x,y,…)`.

```
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Ni}{10}{%
  \begingroup
%      \typeout{Input: -#1-}%
      % get the last eight arguments
      \edef\pgfmath@temp{\pgfmath@util@lasteight#1\relax}%
      % and use them with Hii
      \expandafter\pgfmathHii@\pgfmath@temp
      % and save their result
      \let\pgfmath@Hii\pgfmathresult
      % and Hji
      \expandafter\pgfmathHji@\pgfmath@temp
      \let\pgfmath@Hji\pgfmathresult
      % and Hki
      \expandafter\pgfmathHki@\pgfmath@temp
      \let\pgfmath@Hki\pgfmathresult
      % and Hli
      \expandafter\pgfmathHli@\pgfmath@temp
      \let\pgfmath@Hli\pgfmathresult
      %
      % get the first (x)
      \edef\pgfmath@temp{\pgfmath@util@firstofmany#1\relax}%
      % multiply it with Hji
      \pgfmathmultiply@{\pgfmath@temp}{\pgfmath@Hji}%
      \let\pgfmath@Hji\pgfmathresult
      % and Hli
      \pgfmathmultiply@{\pgfmath@temp}{\pgfmath@Hli}%
      \let\pgfmath@Hli\pgfmathresult
      %
      % get the second (y)
      \edef\pgfmath@temp{\pgfmath@util@secondofmany#1\relax}%
      % multiply it with Hki
      \pgfmathmultiply@{\pgfmath@temp}{\pgfmath@Hki}%
      \let\pgfmath@Hki\pgfmathresult
      % and also with Hli (which was already multiplied with the first)
      \pgfmathmultiply@{\pgfmath@temp}{\pgfmath@Hli}%
      \let\pgfmath@Hli\pgfmathresult
      %
      % add it all together (\pgfmathadd@ ...)
      \pgfmathparse{\pgfmath@Hii+\pgfmath@Hji+\pgfmath@Hki+\pgfmath@Hli}%
%      \typeout{Result: \pgfmathresult}%
      \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
  \endgroup
}
\def\pgfmath@util@lasteight#1#2#3\relax{#3}%
\def\pgfmath@util@firstofmany#1#2\relax{#1}%
\def\pgfmath@util@secondofmany#1#2#3\relax{#2}%
\makeatother
```

Basically, we're using three helper macros that return

- all but the first two
- just the first (`x`) or
- just the second (`y`)

argument. Since in the first case we have these arguments in the form of `{1}{2}{3}{…}{8}` we should use them directly with `\pgfmathHii` or `\pgfmathHii@` and we cannot use `\pgfmathparse`.
The rest of the function is just multiplications and additions.

We can then use it as such:

```
\addplot3[surf, domain=-1:1, y domain=-1:1, samples=41]
  {Ni(abs(x),abs(y),0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1)/det(0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1)};
```

That said, I think the following approach using pre-calculated values is better, it certainly is faster (factor 3).

---

Either way, since most of these values are fixed and not dependent on `x` and `y` I'd circumvent the problem by using a two-parameter function `Nxy(x,y)` (and later `NxyDet(x,y)` that includes the `det` factor) that uses values stored in some value-keys.

Additionally, instead of storing all eight other parameters, I will precalculate the fixed parts (since neither `det`, `factor`, `factorx`, `factory` nor `factorxy` is dependent on `x` or `y`).

To make it easier to evaluate and store the returned value in a value-key I'm using a special key handler `.pgfmath` – or rather `.pgfmath fpu` because PGFPlots uses `fpu` internally – that evaluates the given value and returns the result to the key.

The function `Nxy` just uses these four values and adds those according to your original function

```
Nxy(x, y) = factor + factorx * x + factory * y + factorxy * x * y
```

Inside of the defintion of `Nxy` I define a shortcut macro for `\pgfkeysvalueof` which will not survive this function definition since it is only defined inside the group.

Since the factor `det` is also fixed and not dependent of `x` or `y`, I'll also provide a `NxyDet` function that uses our own custom `Nxy` function and just divides its return by the pre-calculated `det` value.

---

When you `\pgfdeclare` a `function{<name>}` two macros will be created:

1. `\pgfmath<name>` and
2. `\pgfmath<name>@`.

The first one is the public interface where we can use any other PGFmath expression, e.g. `\pgfmathNxy{1+2}{17/2*sqrt(2)}`, which will be evaluated *and* parsed by PGFmath as usual (and just saves on parsing step compared to `\pgfmathparse{Nxy(1+2, 17/2*sqrt(2))}`).

The second version only accepts already evaluated parameters (and is used internally by `\pgfmath<name>`).
In the body of `\pgfdeclarefunction` we actually define the second version which will be wrapped by PGFMath in the first version and we can expect `#1` and `#2` to be already parsed and evaluated and to be containing only a value.

And, thus, we can use directly `\pgfmathNxy@` in `NxyDet` and save us another parsing step.

We could have just written

```
\pgfmathparse{Nxy(#1,#2)/\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/helper/det}}
```

too and that would work as well.

---

Instead of `.pgfmath fpu` we could have used

```
prepare matrix/.style={
  /utils/exec=\pgfset{fpu}\pgfmathparse{Hii(#1)},
  helper/Hii/.expanded=\pgfmathresult,
  /utils/exec=\pgfmathparse{Hji(#1)},
  helper/Hji/.expanded=\pgfmathresult,
  /utils/exec=\pgfmathparse{Hki(#1)},
  helper/Hki/.expanded=\pgfmathresult,
  /utils/exec=\pgfmathparse{Hli(#1)},
  helper/Hli/.expanded=\pgfmathresult,
  /utils/exec=\pgfmathparse{detG(#1)}\pgfset{fpu=false},
  helper/detG/.expanded=\pgfmathresult,
}
```

or any other way to calculate five values and store them somewhere like

```
prepare matrix/.code={
  \pgfset{fpu}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\myHii{Hii(#1)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\myHji{Hji(#1)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\myHki{Hki(#1)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\myHli{Hli(#1)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\mydetG{detG(#1)}%
  \pgfset{fpu=false}%
}
```

and then juse use these macros but PGFkeys makes it pretty simple in my opinion and then we already have proper namespaced macros/keys.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{det}{8}{%
  \pgfmathparse{-(#1*(#7*(#4-#6)*(#2-#8)-#5*(#2-#6)*(#4-#8)+#3*(#2-#4)*(#6-#8))
    +#3*#5*(#4-#6)*(#2-#8)-#3*#7*(#2-#6)*(#4-#8)+#5*#7*(#2-#4)*(#6-#8))}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hii}{8}{\pgfmathparse{#5*#7*#4*(#6-#8)+#3*#5*( #4-#6)*#8+#3*#7*#6*(-#4+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hij}{8}{\pgfmathparse{#1*#7*#6*(#2-#8)+#1*#5*(-#2+#6)*#8+#5*#7*#2*(-#6+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hik}{8}{\pgfmathparse{#3*#7*#2*(#4-#8)+#1*#3*( #2-#4)*#8+#1*#7*#4*(-#2+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hil}{8}{\pgfmathparse{#1*#5*#4*(#2-#6)+#1*#3*(-#2+#4)*#6+#3*#5*#2*(-#4+#6)}}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hji}{8}{\pgfmathparse{#3*#4*(#6-#8)+#7*( #4-#6)*#8+#5*#6*(-#4+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hjj}{8}{\pgfmathparse{#5*#6*(#2-#8)+#7*(-#2+#6)*#8+#1*#2*(-#6+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hjk}{8}{\pgfmathparse{#1*#2*(#4-#8)+#7*( #2-#4)*#8+#3*#4*(-#2+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hjl}{8}{\pgfmathparse{#3*#4*(#2-#6)+#5*(-#2+#4)*#6+#1*#2*(-#4+#6)}}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hki}{8}{\pgfmathparse{#3*#5*(-#4+#6)+#3*#7*(#4-#8)+#5*#7*(-#6+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hkj}{8}{\pgfmathparse{#1*#5*( #2-#6)+#5*#7*(#6-#8)+#1*#7*(-#2+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hkk}{8}{\pgfmathparse{#1*#3*(-#2+#4)+#1*#7*(#2-#8)+#3*#7*(-#4+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hkl}{8}{\pgfmathparse{#1*#3*( #2-#4)+#3*#5*(#4-#6)+#1*#5*(-#2+#6)}}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hli}{8}{\pgfmathparse{#7*(-#4+#6)+#5*(#4-#8)+#3*(-#6+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hlj}{8}{\pgfmathparse{#7*( #2-#6)+#1*(#6-#8)+#5*(-#2+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hlk}{8}{\pgfmathparse{#7*(-#2+#4)+#3*(#2-#8)+#1*(-#4+#8)}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Hll}{8}{\pgfmathparse{#5*( #2-#4)+#1*(#4-#6)+#3*(-#2+#6)}}

\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Nxy}{2}{%
  \begingroup
    \def\vo##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/helper/##1}}% shortcut for here
    \pgfmathparse{\vo{factor}+\vo{factorx}*#1+\vo{factory}*#2+\vo{factorxy}*#1*#2}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
  \endgroup
}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{NxyDet}{2}{%
  % quicker than \pgfmathparse{Nxy(#1,#2)/\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/helper/det}}
  \pgfmathNxy@{#1}{#2}%
  \pgfmathdivide@{\pgfmathresult}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/helper/det}}%
}

\pgfkeys{
  /handlers/.pgfmath/.code=%
    \pgfmathparse{#1}\expandafter\pgfkeys@exp@call\expandafter{\pgfmathresult},
  /handlers/.pgfmath fpu/.code=%
    \begingroup\pgfset{fpu}\pgfmathparse{#1}\expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\pgfkeys@exp@call\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}}
\makeatother
\pgfplotsset{
  helper/factor/.initial=0,
  helper/factorx/.initial=0,
  helper/factory/.initial=0,
  helper/factorxy/.initial=0,
  helper/det/.initial=0,
  prepare matrix/.style 2 args={
    helper/factor/.pgfmath fpu  ={Hi#1(#2)}, 
    helper/factorx/.pgfmath fpu ={Hj#1(#2)},
    helper/factory/.pgfmath fpu ={Hk#1(#2)},
    helper/factorxy/.pgfmath fpu={Hl#1(#2)},
    helper/det/.pgfmath fpu     ={det(#2)}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[every axis plot/.append style={surf, samples=20}]
\addplot3[domain=0:1, y domain=0:1,
  prepare matrix={i}{ 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}] {NxyDet(x,y)};
\addplot3[domain=-1:0, y domain=0:1,
  prepare matrix={j}{-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,-1, 1}] {NxyDet(x,y)};
\addplot3[domain=-1:0, y domain=-1:0,
  prepare matrix={k}{-1,-1, 0,-1, 0, 0,-1, 0}] {NxyDet(x,y)};
\addplot3[domain=0:1, y domain=-1:0,
  prepare matrix={l}{ 0,-1, 1,-1, 1, 0, 0, 0}] {NxyDet(x,y)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to explain the code a bit?

Comment: Thanks for the details. I've never plotted functions this way in pgfplots so I'm learning about it, before I always used the `declare function` within the tikzpicture options. I'm still a bit lost with the code you wrote. Suppose I have 4 functions I want to actually plot (Ni, Nj, Nk, and Nl), each one with its own and different detG, then I guess I have to replicate by 4 the code you wrote, right?

Comment: Also, it seems that we're only providing information to compute detG in `prepare matrix` within the `addplot3` options. Does that mean that I can change these to change the computation of detG?

Comment: I managed to get the code to plot the 4 functions (see my edit). There's a lot of repeated code, and I'm not sure whether the approach is the right one since I'm using `pgfplotsset` just before each `addplot3` command. I noticed also that I had to give a proper order for the plotting, otherwise the final result wouldn't look fine (part of functions in the back would overlap to the front). What do you think?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Could you include expressions of the functions as LaTeX output? It takes a lot of time to rewrite/guess them from the code (`detG`= determinant, `NiDet`=? ...)

Comment: @aaragon I've plotted all four parts with your function but still with only using five pre-calculated values – a little bit generalized. I wonder if all `H??` functions could be generalized further but I don't know what they mean. Should the plot by symmetrical? Maybe you only need each function with the same eight parameters once but with different signs, i.e. `NxyDet(x,y)`, `(-x,y)`, `(x,-y)` and `(-x,-y)`? But this then becomes more of a math problem than a TikZ one.

Comment: @BlackMild I have only used OP's formulas, nothing's changed.